# CF cache header miss if opened in a different browser

Tags: caching, cloudflare

Please help with how to make the cache header in different browsers have HIT status,

because currently when I open my website with a different browser, the response header doesn't always hit, so the LOG on my server becomes a double GET,

Is there a setting so that there is only one GET on my server, because I use a cache from CF

my log server
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDDxD.png)

chomre browser
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD2lo.png)
mozila browser
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A54iZ.png)
I feel cheated in my website header response,

Is this really what the CF chahce system is like?

please help and advise

Thank You

When I open my website with the same URL in the Chrome browser and the Mozile browser, the response header is different when creating the cache,

how to make it actually cache and only GET it once to the backend server